# Error installing GLFW on mac using cabal for haskell

Tags: macos, opengl, haskell, cabal

I'm have Max OSx 10.6.8, Xcode 3.2.6 (the latest version available for my mac version). I'm using haskell but I'm having trouble using opengl.

I found a suggestion a online like the following:

```
cabal update
cabal install OpenGL
cabal install GLFW
```

My error came in the 3rd command. I got a fatal error, it says:

```
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
GLFW-0.4.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Here is the error out (there is a large amount of warnings which I'm not including for the sake of readability and space):

```
glfw/lib/macosx/macosx_window.c:374:0:
     error: 'typeLongInteger' undeclared (first use in this function)

glfw/lib/macosx/macosx_window.c:374:0:
     error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

glfw/lib/macosx/macosx_window.c:374:0:
     error: for each function it appears in.)
glfw/lib/macosx/macosx_window.c: At top level:

glfw/lib/macosx/macosx_window.c:448:0:
     error: 'kEventWindowDrawContent' undeclared here (not in a function)
glfw/lib/macosx/macosx_window.c: In function '_glfwWindowEventHandler':
```

Any suggestions for how to solve it?

This is the error when I try to load a file that requires graphics:

```
Could not find module `Graphics.UI.GLFW':
```

Comment: When you get an `ExitFailure 1` error, it usually means there was an error earlier on in the build process. Can you paste the output *before* the `cabal: Error:...` bit?

Comment: You read my mind!
I was able to look at the output errors, aside from the warnings here it was it shows.

glfw/lib/macosx/macosx_window.c:374:0:
     error: 'typeLongInteger' undeclared (first use in this function)

glfw/lib/macosx/macosx_window.c:374:0:
     error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

glfw/lib/macosx/macosx_window.c:374:0:
     error: for each function it appears in.)
glfw/lib/macosx/macosx_window.c: At top level:

glfw/lib/macosx/macosx_window.c:448:0:
     error: 'kEventWindowDrawContent' undeclared here (not in a function)

Comment: @lrpr: Comments don't get the same formatting as questions and answers. Can you instead put those errors in your main post, by using the edit button to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cabal, you could try downloading the glfw source tarball and build and install it from the command-line.